# (node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to check if a token is **expired** and I am getting correct results when the JWT is expired, but when the user token is not expired I am getting an error.

```
const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err) => {
    if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
      return res.status(403).send({
        status: 403,
        message: "TokenExpired"
      });
    }
});
req.tokenData = verified;
```

When a token is not expired, I am getting the following error:

> (node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check err first, if `err` is falsy, that means there's no error. else, you can proceed to check the error name with your code.

```js
const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
            return res.status(403).send({
              status: 403,
              message: "TokenExpired"
            });
          }
    } else {
        // token is good
    }

})
```